# I Want to use Different Hosting for my Main Website & its Related Subdomains

Tags: domains, dns, nameserver, cname

I just want to know.

I have registered a domain on Bigrock.com and I want to host its primary domain website on Cloudways servers & its all Subdomains on Godaddy.

Something like this.

www.example.com  -> Hosting on Cloudways
example.com -> -> Hosting on Cloudways

blogs.example.com  -> Hosting on Godaddy
forum.example.com -> Hosting on Godaddy

How this can be done.

Say, I already tried changing A-Records with like below

www.example.com   point to xx.xxx.x.xxx ip  (Cloudways)
blogs.example.com  point to xxx.xx.xx.x ip (GoDaddy)

But it's not updating, is there any other way?

Comment: It can take anywhere from 24-72 hours for DNS changes to propagate out. Sometimes less than 24 hours for some ISPs. How long had it been?? If you continue to worry about it, then can you give use some screen shots of your DNS settings so that we can make sure they are correct?? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you have done is correct. It can take some time to propagate DNS changes across the internet as you have to wait for the cached records to expire to get the updated records from your authorative name server. If you are unsure if your record's have propagated fully take a look at https://www.whatsmydns.net/, it has 21 search points across the globe as of this post located on almost every continent and across the worlds various tier 1 networks and will tell you what your DNS records are at those points. If there are differences between two points on the globe you will know your DNS records haven't fully propagated yet. It also lets you set what you expect the value to be so you can easily see any point where a record has been found but it isn't what it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your DNS is propagated, `A` records will change pretty much immediately.

There is one thing though that you should be aware of: while using Chrome browser, it will cache routing and things very heavily. So you could work to clear those out by wiping your local DNS caches. First run `ipconfig /flushdns` in Windows console to clear system dns cache. Then in Chrome visit `chrome://net-internals/#dns` and hit "Clear host cache". Finally using <kbd>F12</kbd> developer mode in a new tab (does not cache), hold down on the refresh button, drag down, and choose "Empty Cache and Hard Reload". I'm not sure if Firefox or others do the same thing as Chrome.

If it's still displaying incorrectly, Google for a web proxy or VPN you never use and visit your site through it (non-admin areas, don't log in).